# Get blocky look on textures some textures

Tags: xna, c#

If I do this:

`GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.PointWrap;`

All textures I draw are blocky.

`GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearWrap;`

All of my textures are blurred a bit.

What do I have to do so that only some of my textures are blocky and some are blurred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use two separate sprite batches for each type of drawing. One for the blocky. One for the blurry.

Use this overloaded method when you begin your sprite batch:

```
SpriteBatch.Begin (SpriteSortMode, BlendState, SamplerState, DepthStencilState, RasterizerState, Effect)
```

The result should look something like this:

```
SpriteBatch.Begin (SpriteSortMode.Deferred, nil, SamplerState.PointWrap, nil, nil, nil);
//SpriteBatch.Draw(**blocky stuff**);
SpriteBatch.End ();

SpriteBatch.Begin (SpriteSortMode.Deferred, nil, SamplerState.LinearWrap, nil, nil, nil);
//SpriteBatch.Draw(**blurry stuff**);
SpriteBatch.End ();
```

Comment: Or 1 SpriteBatch in immediate mode if you need to switch often. which is much faster then creating and destroying the SpriteBatch.

Comment: @ClassicThunder I think eazimmerman means separate "batches" - not separate `SpriteBatch` objects. Obviously recreating the `SpriteBatch` object (all all its internal resources) is stupidly slow. But it's also unnecessary. You can draw multiple batches (`Begin`/`End` blocks) with the one `SpriteBatch` object. And `SpriteSortMode.Immediate` does the almost the equivalent of putting a `Begin`/`End` call around each `Draw` - so it certainly **doesn't offer any speed improvements**. (The main reason it exists at all is backwards compatibility.)

Comment: @AndrewRussell I have measured significant performance improvements by changing code that required multiple batches (Begin/End sets) to immediate and changing values that would otherwise require a Begin/End set.

Comment: @ClassicThunder Yeah, sorry - I should have been a *lot* less absolute there. Obviously `Immediate` will give you some improvement - because it does less work. It doesn't setup the sprite matrix each time, for example. I just measured it at a 30% improvement for unbatchable sprites (note that this is a CPU/GPU dependent measure). The point I was trying to make was that it is (almost) the same once it hits the GPU/driver. Moreover, if your sprites *are* batchable, then you almost immediately lose that performance edge - so ProgrammerAtWork may well be better off lazily switching batches.

Comment: @AndrewRussell No problem and I agree. I was just wanting to mention the possibility for the sake of completeness.